# Python - do something and continue when process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python, exit-code

I have created a text file content reader - I have created several functions but I can't handle all cases - if some case is not defined, the program returns the message `"Process finished with exit code 1"` - Is it possible to get around this? If there is a problem - `the Process finished with exit code 1` message - then I would like to save the name of the file and continue reading the rest of the files - at the moment it works so that if there is an error the program just stops working - but I want it to save the name of the file with the error and continue working. How to add such a condition to existing functions? 
Please give me some advice

Example of such an error:

```
import pandas as pd
list=['a',2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)

df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
print (df)
```

Can't convert a character into an `int` so an error occurs.
This is only an example of a possible error, but the name of the file where the error occurs should be saved and the loop should continue.

Comment: Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions, please.

Comment: I have written some conditions with regex - the problem occurs if the text I am looking for is not found in the text file - for example, I have a list with elements from 0 to 10 and I am looking for the number 11 - there is no such number in this set and as a result, a message appears - Process finished with exit code 1 - and in this case I would like to save only the name of the file where this message occurred and continue the `for` loop

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than reply with a comment. Your question should be possible to read as a stand-alone entity.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron added - more or less illustrates the problem

Comment: the include code only explains the problem you may encounter, but it doe not show the code you are actually asking about - the processor of the multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't included any code, I assume that the error was created by a block of code. In that case, you can enclose it within a `try` block and add an 'except` block to save the file's name in a file.
for example,

```
try :
    # to read your files
except: # an exception occurred
    # save the file name in a log
    continue
```

try to share your code for better help.

**EDIT 1** : Added an explanation for using plain `except`.

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit), SystemExit does not inherit from Exception. You would have to use except BaseException.

However, this is for a reason:

> This exception inherits from BaseException instead of StandardError or
>   Exception so that it is not accidentally caught by code that catches
>   Exception.

It is unusual to want to handle "real" exceptions in the same way you want to handle SystemExit. You might be better off catching SystemExit explicitly with except SystemExit.

Comment: Please reconsider this answer. Just advising someone to slap a catch-all `try ... execpt` block around their failing code, without even knowing what the issue is with that code, is not a good idea, and is not conducive to good coding.

Comment: Yes, I get your point, but that is what the person is asking in the question. They didn't ask a solution for their failing code, but a suggestion to make the program continue its work even if it failed.

Comment: You may also elaborate why a blank `except` catches a `SystemExit`, but a `except Exception` does not.

Comment: @San the first post was edited and a sample error was added. But how add it to the loop where the function is performed? Just add to the function into `try:` and after `except:` option to save such a file?

Comment: @DeepSea you can add `try ... except` to the block of code where calls to the functions are made. So if an error occurs in either one of the functions, execution of the rest will cease and the processing of the next file will continue.